# How to output using StyledDocument with HTML?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I have a `JTextPane`, and I would like to output text in it using `StyledDocument`. Here is my `StyledDocument` object:

```java
StyledDocument dox = (StyledDocument) textArea.getDocument();

Style style = dox.addStyle("StyleName", null);

StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, Font.SANS_SERIF);
StyleConstants.setFontSize(style, 8);
dox.insertString(dox.getLength(), "<b>Some Text</b>", null);
```

The problem right now is if I edit the text with html code, it does not display the way I want. I want the text to be displayed as bolded instead of literally `<b>Some Text</b>`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *"it does not display the way I want."*  How do you want it?  What does it display?

Comment: i want the text to be displayed as bolded instead of literally "<b>Some Text</b>"

Comment: You're not going to be able to make the text bold in a textarea without much more, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: it's a textPane so it should be able to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did figure it out on my own in the end using HTMLEditorKit, here's the answer for futher reference

```
    StyledDocument dox = (StyledDocument) textArea.getDocument();
    textPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());

    textPane.setText("<b>Some Text</b>");
```

Comment: `textArea` and `textPane`. No actual apparent use of defined style.

Comment: you don't need any StyledDocument for this at all. The given solution just re-parses the whole JTextPane content. //  PS. ".setEditorKit(editorKit)" could also be .setContentType("text/html");